# Enable buttons when User login

Tags: c#

I have two buttons in my 3rd form. What I want to do is when I log in to the system I want to make visible those 2 buttons. I have written my code but its not working properly.

```
 if (count == 1)
 {
      this.Hide();
      MainMenu MainMenu1 = new MainMenu();
      MainMenu1.ShowDialog();

      MainMenu1.button8.Visible = true;
      MainMenu1.button9.Visible = true;                    
 }
 else 
 {
      MessageBox.Show("Invalide Username Or password. . . .Please try again");
      myconn.Close();
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are calling `ShowDialog` and program doesn't go to the next line until you close your window. Use `Show` method instead

```
 MainMenu1.Show();
```

You can take a look at this question for more details:

[why does form.showdialog() works and form.show() doesn't in the following code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12418117/why-does-form-showdialog-works-and-form-show-doesnt-in-the-following-code)

Comment: @DinoBaba, if this solved your question, you should mark it as the answer.

Comment: @downvoter, what's wrong? explain the reason if there is _any_.

Comment: @Selman22, I'm sorry, that was me. I saw my answer's code in your answer after you edited it, so I downvoted because I was afraid mine would be thought of as stealing from your answer. I'm really sorry, this was my bad. I'll gladly upvote you if you edit your answer so I can remove by downvote. :)

Comment: @davidsbro you right I haven't noticed your answer sorry.

Comment: @davidsbro never mind.you say it in your answer,I don't need to say it again :)

Answer (score 2):

Another option instead of @Selman22's answer would be to make the buttons visible before you call `ShowDialog()`.

```
MainMenu1.button8.Visible = true;
MainMenu1.button9.Visible = true;

MainMenu1.ShowDialog();
```