# How to open multiple independent windows in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `Form1` as shown in the image bellow. When I click on the `Open 1st Window` button, it will open the `Form2`. But I can't go back to `Form1` to click on the second `Open 2nd Window` button till I close Form2.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you are using `ShowDialog` method.Use `Show` method instead when you open your second form.`ShowDialog` waits until you close your Form and your program doesn't go to the next line.You can take a look at these question for more details:

- [What's the difference between Show(), ShowDialog() and Application.Run() functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20859048/whats-the-difference-between-show-showdialog-and-application-run-functio)
- [why does form.showdialog() works and form.show() doesn't in the following code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12418117/why-does-form-showdialog-works-and-form-show-doesnt-in-the-following-code)